# Update email bcc recipient in email backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am building a mail backend that should add a specific address to the bcc of an email.

```
from django.conf import settings

from djcelery_email.backends import CeleryEmailBackend


class BCCEmailBackend(CeleryEmailBackend):
    def send_messages(self, email_messages):

        for i, message in enumerate(email_messages):
            if settings.DEFAULT_BCC_EMAIL is not None:
                message.bcc.append(settings.DEFAULT_BCC_EMAIL)
        super().send_messages(email_messages)
```

When I run my test, the bcc is not set.

```
    @override_settings(DEFAULT_BCC_EMAIL="should_be_send@bcc.de")
    def test_default_bcc_email(self):
        self.assertEqual(settings.DEFAULT_BCC_EMAIL, "should_be_send@bcc.de")
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            self.subject, self.text_content, "test@sender.de", ["test@recipient.de"]
        )
        msg.attach_alternative(self.html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()

        #...
        # This test always fails
        self.assertListEqual(m.bcc, ["should_be_send@bcc.de"], "Default bcc should be set")
```

When I set the bcc directly when initialising EmailMultiAlternatives my test is succeeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) as far as tests are concerned:

> Django’s test runner automatically redirects all Django-sent email to a dummy outbox. This lets you test every aspect of sending email – from the number of messages sent to the contents of each message – without actually sending the messages.
>
> The test runner accomplishes this by transparently replacing the normal email backend with a testing backend.

So, your custom backend is never used in your test, which is why it fails. I think the simplest way to address this is to write your test differently, to directly call the `send_messages()` method on your class, e.g.:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    self.subject, self.text_content, "test@sender.de", ["test@recipient.de"])
# Note, you may have to mock out some behaviour of the backend to 
# ensure it doesn't actually send an email.
BCCEmailBackend().send_messages([msg])
# This should pass now
self.assertListEqual(msg.bcc, ["should_be_send@bcc.de"], "Default bcc should be set")
```